# Authlogic: getting an undefined method `password' for #<User:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, passwords, authorization, authlogic

I can't seem to get my User model in Authlogic to understand the 'password' method even though I added "acts_as_authentic" to the model. This problem was also reported on the Authlogic lighthouse, but no one described how they fixed it:

http://binarylogic.lighthouseapp.com/projects/18752/tickets/128-undefined-method-password-on-rails-231#ticket-128-9

The user table exists with all the required fields, and the controllers and everything else is definitely following the tutorial to the letter.

Anyone know what could be wrong?

(Oh, I'm running Rails 2.3.3, Authlogic 2.1.1)

Comment: Since authlogic Works For Me (tm), you have to provide some more info about your error. A stack trace would be nice :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I misspelled "crypted_password" as "crypted_passwond". Arg!

For all those other people out there, be sure you have all the required columns in your database.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your User model is using `acts_as_authentic`:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic
end
```

I did all kinds of troubleshooting and had somehow removed this when I was troubleshooting a different problem.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to rails and your answer avoided me a lot of frustation!

Answer (score 2):

Have you restarted your application since you installed authlogic? With Passenger, `touch tmp/restart.txt` will do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally realized my route for users was wrong. I had mystyped

```
map.resources user
```

when I fixed and changed to this, authlogic recognized the password field

```
map.resources.users
```