# Getting "undefined method `password' for #<User:0x2b95caea8590>" with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, passwords, authlogic

I realize there's a nearly identical question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382723/authlogic-getting-an-undefined-method-password-for-user) but the fix there did not fix my problem.

My Authlogic is working in my development environment but not in my production environment. Below is the error I'm getting.

```
Started GET "/users/new" for 71.205.207.120 at Tue Feb 22 19:24:49 -0800 2011
  Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
Rendered users/_form.html.erb (19.3ms)
Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (21.6ms)
Completed   in 38ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `password' for #<User:0x2b95caea8590>):
    21:   </div>
    22:   <div class="field">
    23:     <%= f.label :password %><br />
    24:     <%= f.password_field :password %>
    25:   </div>
    26:   <div class="field">
    27:     <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  app/views/users/_form.html.erb:24:in `_app_views_users__form_html_erb___1397135998_23961177217120_1124190'
  app/views/users/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users__form_html_erb___1397135998_23961177217120_1124190'
  app/views/users/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___1081160896_23961177226000_0'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:29:in `new'
```

I didn't misspell any of the database columns, I'm already doing `acts_as_authentic` and I have restarted my server, so I'm not sure what else to try. It seems like it must be something to do with my database but my database structure seems to be identical.

Comment: Did you migrate the database on production server?

Comment: Yes, and I verified that my database changes showed up.

Comment: what about restarting the production server? Not the OS server, just the rails service.

Comment: Try running a rails console on the production server and run this: User.new.methods.grep /^password/ Does it return a :password method there?

Comment: @CalebHC: No, it doesn't. In development, it does but in production it doesn't. Any suggestions for what to do next?

Comment: @Jesse: I tried that already. @ddd: Yes.

Comment: Hmmm... strange. How are you hosting your production app? Are you using apache/nginx or Heroku?

Comment: Also, try running "gem list authlogic" on the production server and see if it returns the version of authlogic.

Answer (score 1):

Database password field (and/or salt field) may not match any of the defaults!!!

I've had this problem twice now and in both cases it was tricky because of two things:

1) The message "undefined method 'password' really (often) means password field not found in database using defaults.

2) The location to ADD your database field for password (or salt for that matter) is NOT anywhere in your applications directory, it in your ruby gem directory, something like ~/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/authlogic-2.1.6/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic !

The field to change is password.rb.  Add your field name(s) in to the list, e.g. i added pd_hashed changed:

module Config
    # The name of the crypted_password field in the database.
    #
    # * Default: :crypted_password, :encrypted_password, :password_hash, or :pw_hash
    # * Accepts: Symbol
    def crypted_password_field(value = nil)
      rw_config(:crypted_password_field, value, first_column_to_exist(nil, :pd_hashed, :crypted_password, :encrypted_password, :password_hash, :pw_hash))
    end

Do the same for the salt field.

Restart and this may help.